# Multipart data Alamofire with JSON parameters

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I am trying to send upload image through multipartFormData

I want to send something like this:

```
{
    'user': {
        'id': 'toto',
        // …
        picture: // the image data
    }
}
```

How is it possible to handle this format with a multipartFormData object ?

For the moment I have this code which works well but it doesn't have the JSON format above :

```
multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: dataImage, name: "picture")
if let parameters = parameters {
     for (key, value) in parameters {
                    multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: value.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, name :key)
                }
      }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
if let _image = image {
    if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_image, 0.5) {
        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: imageName, fileName: "avatar.png", mimeType: "image/png")
    }
}

if let parameters = parameters {
    for (key, value) in parameters {
        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: value.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name: key)
     }
}
```

But parameters need to be like:

```
let parameters:[String: AnyObject] = [
        "user[id]":1
]
```

And image name should be `user[picture]`

That worked for me

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have pretty much the same result to that. But now I need to put all the data in multipartFormData in a field user in a directory.

Comment: Naming the image like: `user[picture]` worked for me.... and paramaters example in answer......

Comment: awwww ok !! you mean in the append data : multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: "user[picture]") ?

Comment: Didn't work for me. Strange. maybe something is wrong in the server side.